# How i could convert Persian numbers to English numbers using QLocale?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtime, qlocale

I want to convert Persian numbers to English numbers using `QLocale`, i wrote this code but it fail:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    QLocale english_number(QLocale::Language::English, QLocale::Country::UnitedStates);
    QTime time;

    time = english_number.toTime("۱۲:۳۲", "HH:mm");

    qDebug() << time;
}
```

**Console output:**

```sh
QTime(Invalid)
```

But it's possible to convert English numbers to Persian numbers:

```cpp
QLocale persian_number(QLocale::Language::Persian, QLocale::Country::Iran);

time = persian_number.toTime("13:32", "HH:mm");

qDebug() << time;
```

**Console Output:**

```sh
QTime("13:32:00.000")
```

Where did i go wrong ?

- **Qt:** 5.14.1
- **OS:** Archlinux-5.6.7-arch1-1
- **Compiler:** GCC 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a Qt Bug, for doing this before converting to `QTime` we need to convert Persian numbers to `int` and then convert to `QTime`.